# How to write variables in between single quotes in a textfile in python?

Tags: python, text-files, quotes

I have a bunch of strings to write in a text file. I want the strings to be written in simple quotes in the file, so I tried using this code: `file.write("the variable is = \"" + my_string + "\" ")` I wanted the output in the txt file to be: `the variable is = 'my_string'` but instead I get `the variable is = "my_string"` in double quotes.

What should I do to get the right output?

Comment: file.write(f"the variable is = '{variable_name}' ") Can you try this ?

Comment: You explicitly wrote double quotes with `\"`. I'd use f-strings as suggested by Deepak Tripathi, but simply `"the variable is = '" + my_string +"'"` works, too, with literal `'` in the string.

Comment: You could always use: `repr(my_string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all for your advice !! It worked well with the solution proposed by  Deepak Tripathi, which is `file.write(f"the variable is = '{variable_name}' ")` ! Thanks, thats exactly what i nedeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if this works

file.write("the variable is = '" + my_string + "' ")

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes inside a string marked by a double quote pair will make the single quote as normal character.

```py
with open("text.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write("the variable is = 'my string'")
```

[image]